# Facebook login with passport return correct requested scopes on local but missing user_posts and user_link on public site (dev)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, passport-facebook

I am using [passport-facebook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-facebook) library with expressjs. My facebook app was in development mode, and my account has developer role. The below code declare 2 scopes user_posts and user_link. Everything working fine on localhost, I got full permissions as expected.

```
  router.get(
    `/auth/${loginType}`,
    /* some middleware */
    passport.authenticate(loginType, { scope: ['user_posts', 'user_link'] })
  );
  router.get(
    `/auth/${loginType}/callback`,
    passport.authenticate(loginType, {
      failureRedirect: '/',
      scope: ['user_posts', 'user_link'],
    }),
    /* some middleware */
  );
```

But on public site (develop environment), I only have default `public_profile` permission
[here is the pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp0rI.png)
What can be the cause of this?
Edited: Both environment using the same api key so there is no way i am using the wrong app

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I left the domains textbox empty in the basic settings of the app and everything is good now. I dont know why there is no document about this